# How do I stop my gun from pointing at the player?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm making a game where you shoot enemies in Unity, but I can't figure out how to stop the player from pointing the gun at himself.

I've tried detecting if the gun is on the left side of the player and if it's rotation on the z-axis is less than 0, but no luck

[image: The gun pointing at the player]

Here's the code for the gun:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GunController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool testbool;

    public Transform player;
    public CharacterController2D playercontroller;
    public float smoothness = 0.125f;
    public float winglength = 2;
    private Vector2 difference;
    bool facingright = false;

    public GameObject bullet;
    public int maxammo;
    private int ammo;
    private bool firing;
    public Vector3 bulletspawnpos;

    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    public Texture2D normalGun;
    public Texture2D emptyGun;
    public GameObject emptyBottle;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        player = transform.parent.transform;
        ammo = maxammo;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        firing = false;
        bool wasfacingright = facingright;
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) & ammo !>= 0 & !firing )
        {
            firing = true;
            Instantiate(bullet, transform.position+bulletspawnpos, transform.rotation);
        }
        if (player.transform.position.x - transform.position.x < 0)
        {
            facingright = false;
            sprite.flipY = false;
        }
        if (player.transform.position.x - transform.position.x > 0)
        {
            facingright = true;
            sprite.flipY = true;
        }        
        if (wasfacingright != facingright) { playercontroller.Flip(); }

        difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float rot = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
       
        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - player.position;
        pos.z = 0;
        Vector3 desiredpos = player.position + (winglength * pos.normalized);
        Vector3 smoothpos = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredpos, smoothness);
        transform.position = smoothpos;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rot);

    }
}
```

Before you point out that the ammo doesn't go down, just know I didn't add that for testing purposes.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "the gun pointing at yourself". Can you perhaps add a couple screenshots which illustrate the problem?

Comment: Why do you ammo!>=0, shouldn't it be ammo>0?

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that it is pointing to the camera, and not the player. It happened to me.

Comment: Can you indicate which pieces of code are responsible for pointing the gun at the camera, and how you'd recommend fixing them?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/105782)